# Shell script to gcc Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, bash, gcc

I am practicing Objective-C under Ubuntu using gcc 4.8.2.

I compile my Objective-C programs like so:

```
gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -lgnustep-base demo.m -o demo -I
/usr/include/GNUstep/ -L /usr/lib/GNUstep/ -lobjc -lgnustep-base
```

All good, but I thought that's too much, why don't I create a shell script to do it. So, I have this following bash script in file ccc.sh:

```
  #!/bin/bash 

  gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -lgnustep-base "$1" -o "$2" 
  -I /usr/include/GNUstep/ -L /usr/lib/GNUstep/ -lobjc -lgnustep-base
```

But, when I run `./ccc.sh demo.m demo` , I get all types of undefined reference errors:

```
/home/stack0verflow/oc/demo.m:35: undefined reference to `objc_msg_lookup'
/home/stack0verflow/oc/demo.m:35: undefined reference to `objc_msg_lookup'
/home/stack0verflow/oc/demo.m:36: undefined reference to `objc_msg_lookup'
/home/stack0verflow/oc/demo.m:37: undefined reference to `objc_msg_lookup'
/home/stack0verflow/oc/demo.m:39: undefined reference to `objc_msg_lookup'
/home/stack0verflow/oc/demo.m:40: undefined reference to `NSLog'
/home/stack0verflow/oc/demo.m:42: undefined reference to `objc_get_class'
```

What am I missing in my shell script?  Thank you.

Comment: Code formatting is different than quoted text. Use the `{}` icon.

Comment: Thanks, looks much better now.

Comment: You can run that **exact** command manually and it works?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, stupid. Can't break up the gcc command line in my shell script. Once I edited it and make sure that the entire command sits in a single line, `./ccc.sh demo.m demo` worked.

Comment: There should also have been an error about `-I` or `/usr/include/GNUstep/` not being a valid command.

Comment: Yes, just reverted ccc.sh and confirmed what you said. Look: `./ccc.sh: line 3: -I: command not found`

Comment: So, shell script does not like to break up a single command into different lines. Just saw from http://superuser.com/questions/508507/linux-bash-script-single-command-but-multiple-lines that to break up a single command in shell script, use the back slash \.

Comment: Think about it. How can the shell know where one command ends and the next begins? It uses semi-colons and newlines for that.

Comment: Yes, very new to shell scripting. Are you saying semi colons are allowed?

Comment: Ah, just tested. It seems semi-colons are optional, much like JavaScript.

Comment: Correct. Newlines and semi-colons provide the same command separation. You need one-or-the-other but both is ok too.

Comment: That is the take-home message for shell script newbies.